# Can the camera position be specified in an SDF file?

Tags: ros, gazebo, sdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am converting a Gazebo 0.x world file into Gazebo 1.x SDF format. In the original file, I was able to specify the initial camera position like this:

```
<rendering:gui>
  <frames>
    <row height="100%">
      <camera width="100%">
        <xyz>85.52 3.6 1.92</xyz>
        <rpy>0 23.8 69.9</rpy>
      </camera>
    </row>
  </frames>
</rendering:gui>
```

Does SDF provide similar functionality? I can't find any in the SDF documentation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38310/can-the-camera-position-be-specified-in-an-sdf-file?/) by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 792 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I looked through the Gazebo 1.0.2 source files, and found that the initial camera pose can be specified like this:

```
<gui>
  <camera name="user_camera">
    <origin pose="85.52 3.6 1.92 0 0.4154 1.22"/>
  </camera>
</gui>
```

---

Originally posted by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) with karma: 792 on 2012-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2